# Flink MySQL connector limit connection

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using flink mysql connector with a single executor of 32Gb RAM, 16vCPU with 32 slots. If I run a job with parallelism 32 (job parallelism 224) that is doing temporal lookup joins with 10 MySQL tables, it starts to fail after 2-3 successful runs with below error.

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:228)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:218)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:209)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:679)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:316)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:314)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
    at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
    at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: open() failed.
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcRowDataLookupFunction.open(JdbcRowDataLookupFunction.java:138)
    at LookupFunction$55178.open(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:34)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.join.lookup.LookupJoinRunner.open(LookupJoinRunner.java:67)
    at org.apache.flink.table.runtime.operators.join.lookup.LookupJoinWithCalcRunner.open(LookupJoinWithCalcRunner.java:51)
    at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:34)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.ProcessOperator.open(ProcessOperator.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:110)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:711)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$1.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:687)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:654)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:766)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:335)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2220)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2015)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:768)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:403)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:385)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:323)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.internal.connection.SimpleJdbcConnectionProvider.getOrEstablishConnection(SimpleJdbcConnectionProvider.java:121)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcRowDataLookupFunction.establishConnectionAndStatement(JdbcRowDataLookupFunction.java:211)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcRowDataLookupFunction.open(JdbcRowDataLookupFunction.java:129)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:478)
    at java.net.Socket.getImpl(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.setTcpNoDelay(Socket.java:998)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.configureSocket(StandardSocketFactory.java:132)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:203)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:299)
    ... 32 more
```

Did Some debugging, the process list on MySQL shows ~ 2* (total job parallelism) connections, i.e. 448 connections from Task Manager IP. The output of `lsof | grep mysql-cj- | wc -l` on task manager also reached to 12k from 3k. But after cancelling job, sometime this number doesn't go down. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is mainly because there are too many connections requesting mysql at the same time. Provide several optimization ideas for reference

1. Consider reducing the total concurrency of tasks
2. By default, lookup cache is not enabled. You can enable it by setting both lookup.cache.max-rows and lookup.cache.ttl, refer to https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/